# What is Stack Exchange's stance on users that move Playground insults elsewhere?

Tags: discussion, comments, offensive

Yesterday, on Stack Overflow, I gave some constructive criticism to a user, when I downvoted (how foolish of me, I know!). Unfortunately as some users do, my point was taking poorly; in this case it was advice that a `WHILE` loop in T-SQL would perform awfully vs a set-based method and provided a couple of fiddles to do so (which evidenced a huge performance difference).

After a few comments I disengaged as the other user wasn't going to listen and also started to throw play ground insults out; I flagged the comments, moved on.

Unfortunately, they decided to instead start posting comments on my website (which he would have found via my profile). One of these said "Stupid Prostitute" in Turkish, another was the "Right Clicker"  insult they were throwing at me in the answers comments, and also the swear word for "poo".

Now, these don't offend me, this is just a small troll on the internet, but the behaviour is clearly not something that any SE community would want. They clearly aren't going to contribute constructively to any communities.

I realise that I "technically" have no proof, however, the fact that they hurled the same insult is a good indicator.

Does SE have an opinion on such user behaviour, even though they've moved off site?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ no, they aren't "stalking" me, or certainly not since. They threw the insults in the comments on SO, then on the website. I haven't seen anything since, and that's specifically about blocking on an SE community; which I know does not exist. My question is purely about what is SE's opinion on users that display the above behaviour.

Comment: _"Unfortunately, they decided to instead start posting comments on my website"_ How's that not considered _stalking_?Flag for moderator intervention.

Comment: Everything in the linked duplicate is related to comments on The SE Communities though, @πάνταῥεῖ . It doesn't actually reference to going off-site and hence my question.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337339/1426539

Comment: There is a form of prevention, which is to know when not to comment. Otherwise one may find themselves in a position where it's too late, and the damage has been done.

Comment: This is why I disengaged, @E_net4theunsafe. I don't tend to comment too much on downvotes because of the childish behaviour people have, however, sometimes I do wish to explain so (I had already posted my own answer on the question, so had addressed that point). I'm afraid none of us know how a user will react until after they have done so.

Comment: Thanks @yivi . Interesting that the other link (from Robert) has a quite different most upvoted answer, however, the moderator response there (from Tim Post) does align similarly to that of Flexo in yours.

Comment: Indeed, this is why we can't have nice things.